# Using normal python variables and writing them into configparser

Tags: python, variables, configparser

Hello I'm just starting out with my first python projects. The python variable "key_name" is asked from the user. This variable should then be written into the configparser file under the section [keys] -> personal. Basically where the "{}" are. And I can't quite figure it out.

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
key_name = input("\nPublic key name: ")
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config['keys']['personal'] = '{}'.format(key_name)
    with open("./data/settings.ini", "w") as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

Comment: How exactly does not "not work"?

Comment: Note that `input` always returns a string, so your call to `format` isn't really doing anything. You could equivalently write `config['keys']['personal'] = key_name`.

Comment: @chepner Thank you so much, I didn't realize I could just write the variable like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to initialize `config['keys']` before you can add variables to that section. (You will also need to ensure that `./data` exists before calling `open`; it can create the file `settings.ini` in that directory, but it will not create the directory for you.)

```
key_name = input("\nPublic key name: ")
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config['keys'] = {}
config['keys']['personal'] = key_name
with open("./data/settings.ini", "w") as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```